# How to select value option in dropdown menu that changes value daily using Selenium/Java

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to select an option within a dropdown menu. I am currently using

```
Select dropdown2 = new Select(driver1.findElement(By.id( "owucChapsSwift2v0InternationalTransactionLanding_ddlCurrency")));
            dropdown2.selectByValue("GBP;British Pound;1.0000;25000.00;000001;29/08/2030 12:00:06;0.000000");
```

However the option within the code changes daily so if i put in

```
"GBP;British Pound;1.0000;25000.00;000001;29/08/2030 12:00:06;0.000000"
```

By tomorrow it will fail as the option value will update with the date/time.

The HTML code is

```
        <td class="dataLabel_33">
                <span class="inputLabel">
                <label for="ddlCurrency">Currency:</label>
                </span>
            </td>
            <td class="dataLabel">
                <select name="owucChapsSwift2v0InternationalTransactionLanding$ddlCurrency" id="owucChapsSwift2v0InternationalTransactionLanding_ddlCurrency" class="dropdown" onchange="ddlCurrency_onChange()">
<option selected="selected" value="0">Please select a currency</option>
<option value="AED;U.A.E Dirham;4.5224;113060.00;2407499358;30/08/2023 13:00:07;0.078600">AED  (U.A.E Dirham)</option>
<option value="AMD;Armenian Dram;472.1856;11804640.00;2407499668;30/08/2023 13:00:07;8.207700">AMD  (Armenian Dram)</option>
<option value="AUD;Australian Dollar;1.9142;47855.00;2407499428;30/08/2023 13:00:07;0.033300">AUD  (Australian Dollar)</option>
<option value="BBD;Barbados Dollar;2.7064;67660.00;1805202111;19/05/2021 13:41:24;0.000000">BBD  (Barbados Dollar)</option>
<option value="BGN;Bulgarian Lev;2.2278;55695.00;2407498828;30/08/2023 13:00:07;0.038700">BGN  (Bulgarian Lev)</option>
<option value="CAD;Canadian Dollar;1.6762;41905.00;2407498688;30/08/2023 13:00:07;0.029200">CAD  (Canadian Dollar)</option>
<option value="CHF;Swiss Franc;1.0900;27250.00;2407498808;30/08/2023 13:00:07;0.018900">CHF  (Swiss Franc)</option>
<option value="CZK;Czech Republic Koruna;27.5259;688147.50;2407499388;30/08/2023 13:00:07;0.478400">CZK  (Czech Republic Koruna)</option>
<option value="DKK;Danish Krona;8.4910;212275.00;2407498708;30/08/2023 13:00:07;0.147600">DKK  (Danish Krona)</option>
<option value="DZD;Algerian Dinar;167.6281;4190702.50;2407498678;30/08/2023 13:00:07;2.913800">DZD  (Algerian Dinar)</option>
<option value="EUR;Euro;1.1393;28482.50;2407499368;30/08/2023 13:00:07;0.019800">EUR  (Euro)</option>
<option value="GBP;British Pound;1.0000;25000.00;000001;29/08/2030 12:00:06;0.000000">GBP  (British Pound)</option>
```

Tried dropdown2.selectByValue("GBP;British Pound;1.0000;25000.00;000001;29/08/2030 12:00:06;0.000000");
which will work today (29/08/2023) but will fail after todays date

I have also tried dropdown2.selectByVisableText("GBP"); But that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```java
// Locate the dropdown element
WebElement dropdownElement = driver.findElement(By.id("dropdownId"));

// Create a Select object
Select select = new Select(dropdownElement);

// Get the selected option or you can choose the element with loop.
WebElement selectedOption = select.getFirstSelectedOption();

// Get the value attribute
String valueAttribute = selectedOption.getAttribute("value");
System.out.println("Value attribute: " + valueAttribute);
```

Comment: Could you explain further as I'm not sure how this would work? I need selenium to select the GPB option from the dropdown menu. select.getFirstSelectedOption(); would select the wrong option?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).